# Is it possible weblogic stuck threads ever clear up without rebooting?

Tags: java, multithreading, weblogic

Our server is on last leg window XP. For some unforeseen reason `weblogic 10.1`. Thread is stuck and `weblogic` console is unresponsive. Since, it is old server, if we reboot it might not boot up. How do we resolve the issue without restarting server? We are hosting only one instance on the server.

Comment: Whether it is old or new server, why it will not reboot ?? If WL console is unresponsive then it means that you Admin server thread is stuck, so you need to kill you Admin server Java process and restart it .. As per my best knowledge you cannot do it without re-boot ..

Comment: Potentially, you could go to the weblogic admin console and restart the application. Also, Windows XP is eol and you know it.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch OP has mentioned - *weblogic console is unresponsive*, so how we can go to WL admin console. He has to kill the admin server process and restart ..

Comment: @hagrawal good point. I'm still baffled why they chose to use xp as a production server.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, a typical choice.